# Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type String?

Tags: kotlin

```
fun checkLengthA(str : String?): Int = if (str.isNullOrBlank()) 0 else str.length
```

*"Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type String?*

all null objects (or empty) are caught by isNullOrBlank(), so the str object in str.length can never be null (or empty). This can be achieved by replacing extension function with an explicit check.

```
fun checkLengthB(str : String?): Int = if (str == null) 0 else str.length
```

or less verbose expression:

```
fun checkLengthC(str : String?): Int = str?.length ?: 0
```

Both checkLengthB and checkLengthC will run without problems.

Let's remove the nullable type from checkLengthA to avoid the compile error, highlighted above:

```
fun checkLengthA(str : String): Int = if (str.isNullOrBlank()) 0 else str.length
```

Now, we are only allowed to pars use non-null parameter of type String, so if we expect some null types then we have to put the "?" back.

Looks like the complier does not understand that str of type String will never evaluate to null when running str.length and an extension function, but it will compile without problems if we use (str == null) in the if-else statement.

Can anyone explain why it is happening?

Answer (score 9):

There is no way for the compiler to prove that after `isNullOrBlank` evaluates to `false`, that the argument must not be null. `isNullOrBlank` is just a normal method, the same argument could apply to any number of functions that check whether an argument is null. What if someone changed the implementation of `isNullOrBlank` to always return `false`?

In the case of `arg == null`, the compiler *knows* that this must mean the argument is not null, as, well, that's exactly what `== null` means, syntactically and literally.

Note that `== null` does not always result in a safe cast, for example, when the variable being checked is a property.

In this case:

```
str?.length ?: 0
```

there are no smart casts involved.

`str?.length` is an `Int?`, and with the Elvis operator `?:` you will end up with an `Int`.

---

Interestingly, [the implementation of `isNullOrBlank`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.2.20/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/text/Strings.kt#L263) contains this `contract`:

```
contract {
    returns(false) implies (this@isNullOrBlank != null)
}
```

so maybe this will be supported at some point.

Comment: My understanding was that isNullOrBlank extension function should perform str != null check so the compiler would not complain. I don't fully understand what it does; the "contract" part is new for me.

Comment: @pitos Yes, it does, but this is in another function - it can't compile, since the code _in_ the function (the Kotlin stdlibs) may change at some point, since a function is really just another layer of abstraction. (It _probably_ won't change, since it is so simple, but the point still stands - it's just a function).

Comment: @pitos good news: [Kotlin 1.3 will support `contract`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew13.html#contracts) (though custom `contract`s are experimental).